# Jetpack Compose: Move children element out of box

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Can't move "LIVE" element out of the box to the right side, padding start on Surface doesn't work here. Red color - current element position, green - that should be (move to the right side 16.dp)

[image: Red current position, green that should be]

```
@Composable
fun UserAvatarProfile(
    @DrawableRes drawable: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier,
        contentAlignment = Alignment.TopEnd
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = drawable),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(120.dp)
                .border(
                    BorderStroke(2.dp, Color.White),
                    CircleShape
                )
                .clip(CircleShape)
        )
        Surface(
            shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp, top = 16.dp)
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier
            ) {
                Icon(
                    Icons.Default.AddCircle,
                    contentDescription = null
                )
                Text(
                    text = "LIVE",
                    modifier.padding(end = 8.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```